# Why aren't SCM diff decorations showing in the VS Code gutter in VS Code 1.76.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and my changes are showing under source control and I can see the details when I click on them, but I used to see green and red indicators on the line numbers when I was writing code. I can't see them anymore. How can I fix this?

It sometimes works on some files, but doesn't work on many other files.

Before:

[image]

Now:

[image]

[image]

I want it to appear as it is in the 'before' photo. I reset the settings etc. The strange thing is that this works on some files but not on others. I am saving all the files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't SCM diff decorations showing in the gutter in VS Code 1.76.1?](/q/75715788)

Comment: Solved with VSCode 1.76.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

1. I deleted the C:\Users\myUser .vscode folder.
2. I deleted the C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming code folder.
3. I completely uninstalled Visual Studio Code from "Programs and
   Features".
4. I restarted my computer.
5. I reinstalled Vs Code.

And the problem was solved.

#### Update 03.15.2023

This method seemed to have solved my problem at first, but later I realized that it was due to version 1.76, so I completely removed Visual Studio Code version 1.76 from my computer and downloaded version 1.75 from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75. And I turned off automatic updates for Visual Studio Code.

> **Settings** -> **Find for Update: Mode** -> **select none**

I did not encounter this bug in version 1.75.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue happen on version 1.76.1.

Downgrading to version 1.75.1 and disabling auto updates fixed the issue for me.

Looks like it's probably a bug with the latest version (1.76.1)