# Why aren't SCM diff decorations showing in the gutter in VS Code 1.76.1?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VS Code always adds a highlight to the [gutter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_gutter-indicators) when lines of code have been changed and now it stopped working in all my repositories, but git changes are still tracked in the Source Control Manager panel.

*Environment:*

- VSCode version 1.76.1
- Win 10
- git version 2.39.2.windows.1

*Steps that did not solve the problem:*

- reboot editor and PC
- update git to latest version
- initialization of a new git project

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75709132/11107541

Comment: Solved with VSCode 1.76.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably a case of the following reported bug in VS Code 1.76.1: [Git decorations not shown in 1.76.1 #176749](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176749). That issue ticket got closed in favour of [Git gutter not shown in workspace with multiple folders
#176738](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176738), where the issue has been purportedly fixed for the latest insiders version of VS Code. You can indicate that you are also experiencing a similar issue by giving it a thumbs up reaction.

The issue should be fixed in version 1.76.2, so try updating to that first.

Other workarounds include rolling back to VS Code 1.76.0, but do know that that version also has its own bugs.

I've also heard that someone got rid of the issue by deleting all their VS Code config/state/cache folders and reinstalling, but I personally wouldn't do that. I'd rather just hold onto that config/state/cache info and wait for fixes.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found this by googling "`github vscode issues git gutter not working`" and filtering for results from the past month.

Comment: Downgrading to version 1.75.1 fixed this issue.

Comment: As mentioned in #176738 above, the 3/14 Insiders release appears to have fixed the issue (for me at least).

Comment: For me, renaming the problematic files (and then naming back) helped to resolve this issue. Not a real solution, but a potential work-around, other than rolling back to v1.76.0 or installing Insider Version.

Comment: I am encountering same issue. Even though the codes are changed, gutter is not showing any changes.

Comment: Updating to 1.76.2 (stable) works, thanks!

Comment: Getting the same problem on insiders 1.79

Comment: @Ramses can you please report an issue ticket using the `Help: Report Issue...` command in [the VS Code command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and then comment here with a link to your issue ticket?

Comment: @starball done https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184638

Comment: I have this issue with vs code 1.80.0. In order to see the changes I must close the file and open it again :(